# Build balanced binary tree with foldr

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary-tree, fold, higher-order-functions

I write the function `foldTree` that build balanced binary tree from list.
I must use `foldr` and it's ok, i used it, but i make `insertInTree` function recursive =( for now i know only this way to walk through the trees =)).

**UPDATE**: iam not sure about function `insertTree`: is it right calculate the heights in recursion?? =(( need some help here.

Is it possible to write `insertInTree` without recursion (something with `until/iterate/unfoldr`) or make `foldTree` function without helper functions => shorter somehow?

this is my try below:

```
data Tree a = Leaf
            | Node Integer (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            deriving (Show, Eq)

foldTree :: [a] -> Tree a
foldTree = foldr (\x tree -> insertInTree x tree) Leaf

insertInTree :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insertInTree x Leaf = Node 0 (Leaf) x (Leaf)
insertInTree x (Node n t1 val t2) = if h1 < h2 
                                    then Node (h2+1) (insertInTree x t1) val t2 
                                    else Node (h1+1) t1 val (insertInTree x t2) 
  where h1 = heightTree t1
        h2 = heightTree t2

heightTree :: Tree a -> Integer
heightTree Leaf = 0
heightTree (Node n t1 val t2) = n
```

output:

```
*Main> foldTree "ABCDEFGHIJ"
Node 3 (Node 2 (Node 0 Leaf 'B' Leaf) 'G' (Node 1 Leaf 'F' (Node 0 Leaf 'C' Leaf))) 'J' (Node 2 (Node 1 Leaf 'D' (Node 0 Leaf 'A' Leaf)) 'I' (Node 1 Leaf 'H' (Node 0 Leaf 'E' Leaf)))
*Main>
```

Comment: What do you think the height of the tree means?  Can you define it?  Does that match what insertInTree computes?

Comment: I have only this definition from my homework task: The
**height** of a binary tree is the length of a path from the root to the deepest node. For example, the height of a tree with a single node is 0; the
height of a tree with three nodes, whose root has two children, is 1; and so on. Oh! something wrong this height computing =((

Comment: Is the task to create the tree from an already-ordered list? Your recursive `insertInTree` is fine. you can make `foldTree = foldr insertInTree Leaf`. Can you clarify what you're asking besides the code-review type stuff?

Comment: iam not sure about insertTree function now: it is right calculate the heights? i mean in- Node (h2+1) Node (h1+1)? and how to make insertTree as couple of pipeline functions?

Comment: Calculating the height is kind of necessary for balancing. You have already saved the height in each node so `heightTree` is O(1).

Comment: the problem with Leaf and Node with two Leafs have the same value of height? **Leaf = 0** and **Node 0 Leaf a Leaf** when i make new node with 1 => **Node 1 Leaf a Leaf** i think all is OK.

Comment: if you do this, your code will definitely be wrong, because your insertion code is in error when the two sub-trees are of equal heights and the right sub-tree is already full.

Comment: FYI, this is homework 4, exercise 2 from Brent Yorgey's course on Haskell: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/04-higher-order.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your insertion function is in error when the two sub-trees' heights are equal, because inserting into the right sub-tree will increase its height if it was already full. It is not immediately clear to me whether such situation will ever arise or not in your code.

The apparently correct way to insert a new element into a tree seems to be

```
insertInTree x (Node n t1 val t2) 
    | h1 < h2   = Node  n (insertInTree x t1) val t2 
    | h1 > h2   = Node  n    t1 val t2n 
    | otherwise = Node (h+1) t1 val t2n  
  where h1  = heightTree t1
        h2  = heightTree t2
        t2n = insertInTree x t2
        h   = heightTree t2n     -- might stay the same
```

This creates *almost balanced* trees (a.k.a. AVL-trees). But it pushes each new element to the very bottom of the tree.

*edit:* These trees can be nicely seen with

```
showTree Leaf = ""  
showTree n@(Node i _ _ _) = go i n
  where
  go _ (Leaf) = "" 
  go i (Node _ l c r) = go (i-1) l ++ 
    replicate (4*fromIntegral i) ' ' ++ show c ++ "\n" ++ go (i-1) r
```

Try

> putStr . showTree $ foldTree "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

And yes, you can write `foldTree` shorter, as

```
foldTree = foldr insertInTree Leaf
```

Answer (score 4):

Just want to point out that the accepted answer is good but will not work after having a height 3 balanced binary tree as it did not consider the fact that the left tree could have less height than the right after inserting.

Apparently, the code could've worked adding an extra condition:

```
insertInTree x (Node n t1 val t2) 
    | h1 < h2   = Node  n      t1n val t2 
    | h1 > h2   = Node  n      t1  val t2n
    | nh1 < nh2 = Node  n      t1n val t2
    | otherwise = Node (nh2+1) t1  val t2n 
  where h1  = heightTree t1
        h2  = heightTree t2
        t1n = insertInTree x t1
        t2n = insertInTree x t2
        nh1 = heightTree t1n
        nh2 = heightTree t2n
```

Comment: no, the accepted answer takes all possibilities into consideration, and works as advertised. It creates trees such that for every node in the tree the node's two branches' depths differ by at most 1, aka AVL-trees. There's no problem with depths above 3 that I could find. I've edited the answer with the new function to show these trees in a visual tree-like manner, and a suggested test.

Comment: just tried it with your function; for the test case shown in my answer my function creates tree of depth 7; yours indeed creates more balanced tree, of depth 6; at the price of having more complex code.

Comment: You can achieve more balanced trees by defining the height of a leaf to be -1 (heightTree Leaf = -1) and using @WillNess answer. The resulting tree is not as balanced as this answer but would be more efficient